# onDraw() Alpha channel CPU consumption

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, ondraw

To reach attenuation effect for text on the screen i call canvas.drawColor(0x01FFFFFF) on each draw iteration. I noticed when i use color without alpha channel (e.g. 0xFFFFFFFF) CPU consumption is about 6%, but when i turn on alpha channel the consumption is about 25-30%.
I'm working on live wallpaper and it is important not to overload the CPU.
Is there any way to reduce the CPU consumption?

```
void drawFrame() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {
                c.drawColor(0x01FFFFFF);
                drawOnBitmap();
                c.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mLegacyPixels, 0, mTimePaint);                    
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        // Reschedule the next redraw
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDraw);
        if (mVisible) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mDraw, 1000 / 30);
        }
    }
```